# Customize speed animation for Animated Vector Drawable

Tags: android, animation, animatedvectordrawable

[image: Example of the animated vector]

I have animated vector, which just uses XML object animator. When i start my application, it will just start animating as usual. What i need to do, if my goal is to manipulate duration of animation for some targets or parts via code?